# Angular 2 Observables - Need to wait until operations are done before running Observable

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I've been slowly getting the hang of observables, though Firebase seems to require you to do a lot of crazy stuff with them in order to get achieved results :P Basically, I have a function where I'm filtering out some keys, based on some conditions in order to create an array of users to grab from my Firebase database.

However, the Observable is ran before my filtering function is able to finish, so I'm running into a race condition. My function is a bit complex (At least to me), so I'm not exactly sure what I can do to ensure the `userKeys` are up to date before the `Observable.combineLatest` call gets made:

```js
getUsersForConversations(conversations) {
    conversations.forEach((conversation, index) => {

      // Get user out of local storage
      this.storage.get('user').then(user => {

        // Iterate through the users and remove the current user
        // to prevent an unecessary call being made
        let userKeys = Object.keys(conversation.users);

        userKeys.forEach((key, index) => {
          if(key === user.id) {
            userKeys.splice(index, 1);
          } else {

            if(userKeys.length > 0) {

              // Grab the conversation for this user and determine
              // If the conversation has been removed before
              this._af.database
              .object(`/social/conversations_last_deleted/${conversation.$key}/${user.id}`)
              .subscribe(lastDeleted => {

                if(lastDeleted && (lastDeleted.$value !== null)) {
                  this._messages.getMessagesForConvo(conversation.$key, lastDeleted).subscribe(messages => {

                    if(messages.length === 0) {
                      userKeys.splice(index, 1); // This is updated after the Observable.combineLatest :(
                    }
                  })
                };
              });
            }
          }
        });

        // Get all the users based on this list and shove them
        // into the correct conversation

        Observable.combineLatest(
          userKeys.map((userKey) => this._af.database
            .object(`/social/users/${userKey}`)
          )
        ).subscribe(users => {
          conversations[index].users = users;
          this.conversations = conversations;
        })
      });
    });
  }
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well I try to do all the logic in a Observable please give it a try and remember that you must unsubscribe to the observables!!

```
  getUsersForConversations(conversations) {
    conversations.forEach((conversation, index) => {

      // Get user out of local storage
      this.storage.get('user').then(user => {

        let userKeys = Object.keys(conversation.users);

        let sub = Observable
          .from(userKeys)
          .filter(key => (key != user.id && key.length > 0))
          .flatMap(key =>
            Observable.zip(
              Observable.of(key),
              this._af.database.object(`/social/conversations_last_deleted/${conversation.$key}/${user.id}`)
                .filter(lastDeleted => (lastDeleted && (lastDeleted.$value !== null)))
                .flatMap(lastDeleted => this._messages.getMessagesForConvo(conversation.$key, lastDeleted)),
              (key, messages) => {
                if (messages.length === 0) {
                  return null;
                }
                return key;
              })
          )
          .filter(key => key != null)
          .flatMap(userKey => this._af.database.object(`/social/users/${userKey}`))
          .subscribe(users => {
            conversations[index].users = users;
            this.conversations = conversations;
          });

          // REMEMBER TO ALWAYS UNSUBSCRIBE!!!! or you will have memory leaks....
          sub.unsubscribe();

      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer Victor. I have actually been struggling with this for days. There seems to be a lot going on here, and as I've been tinkering with it, it doesn't seem to quite be doing what I'm expecting :/ For example, if I remove a conversation, the list item still stays there, instead of disappearing. I'm also getting other weird and unexpected things happening. But hmm, so this is the best way to integrate all these calls into one Observable, you think?